# Java Equivilent of a PHP Array

Tags: php, android

I need to send an array to a server but I cannot seem to find the correct formatting for it.

Here is the php equivalent that I need to send

```
array(
      'interest' => 1,
      'charity' => 590,
      'items' => array(
        array(
          'cart_item_id' => 11197,
          'message' => '',
          'aid' => 174
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I am trying to get send my data in nameValuePairs - here is what I am trying

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs  =   new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    if (interest == true) {
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("interest", "1"));                
    } else {
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("interest", "0"));    
    }
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("charity", String.valueOf(charityId)));
    int len = cartItems.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("items[" + String.valueOf(i) + "]" + "[cart_item_id]", String.valueOf(cartItems.get(i).cartItemId)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("items[" + String.valueOf(i) + "]" + "[message]", cartItems.get(i).message));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("items[" + String.valueOf(i) + "]" + "[aid]", String.valueOf(cartItems.get(i).addressId)));
    }
```

This is incorrect tho. As always any help is much appreciated

Edit

For clarification this is what my app sends to the server

```
[interest=0, charity=1878, items[0][cart_item_id]=14498, items[0][message]=, items[0][aid]=315, items[1][cart_item_id]=14499, items[1][message]=, items[1][aid]=318]
```

but that is incorrect

Comment: I think you create problem in for loop,First check name and value proper as per you wish using System.out.prinln();,Mind that you must send string value to server

Comment: The app runs fine. It sends the details to the server but they are formatted incorrectly. I am sending strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `HashMap<Object,Object>` , and then when you want to add the sub array  :

```
array(
          'cart_item_id' => 11197,
          'message' => '',
          'aid' => 174
)
```

just add a new `HashMap<String,String>` into your Super `HashMap<Object,Object>` : the logic will be something like this:

HashMap parentMap = new HashMap();
    HashMap subMap = new HashMap();

```
// put params into parentMap
parentMap.put("key1", "this is a string value");
parentMap.put("key2", 45);
parentMap.put("key3", new Date());

subMap.put("card_item_id", ""+11197);
subMap.put("message", "this is a message from subMap");
parentMap.put("items", subMap);

//get the subMap from the parentMap like this 
HashMap<String, String> copySubMap = (HashMap<String, String>) parentMap.get("items");
```

hope that you got the idea of how formatting your array :)

Comment: That has made it a lot clearer thank you. However that code does not compile. I am getting the error 

The method add(String, String) is undefined for the type HashMap<Object,Object>

is should be put instead of add :)

Comment: i've just write the code without using eclipse ide , so the  problem you got is just a cast or something else. the essential is that you've got the idea of how to resolve your problem . glad to hear it :)

Comment: Yes that it leaves me with the problem of encoding a hashmap now

Comment: I think I was a little quick with awarding the answer. I can't get an the numberous subMaps in the parentMap. I am logging parentMap.toString()

that just shows 1 array of items

Comment: Ok so it turns out the request for formatted correctly. The problem being that the server will only accept "&" between each entry rather than "," that I have been sending. Any help with that problem will be appreciated

Comment: i didn't understand what you want to do. your question is how to transform your array from PHP to JAVA , ask another question about your new problem :) and add some code to explain the problem

Comment: Yes I asked how to format it as I thought i was doing it wrong but infact my formatting was ok. The problem lies else where. Thank you for you time tho

Comment: but your question is not clear enough, do you want to format your hashmap params in a URL or what?? please explain you question , that's why i've told you to post a new question

Comment: it was quite clear and you answered it. However there was no problem where I thought there was one.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `HashMap` in the package java.util. Have a look to the API docs for more details ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input but I was looking how to format the array really. I will look into hash map as it does seem like the correct class to use but it doesn't help me with my question of how the array should be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Java class HashMap should do it.  Uses key-value pair concept.

Here is implementation example, http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-hashmap-example.html

Comment: Thanks for the input but I was looking how to format the array really. I will look into hash map as it does seem like the correct class to use but it doesn't help me with my question of how the array should be formatted